# Standard Button not available in Salesforce1

Tags: button

Some of the Standard button are available on Web page but not on the Salesforce1 page, eg --  Share button. I am not able to figure out why this is not available.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the sharing button is not available is that there is no Salesforce1 specific sharing functionality exposed at the moment.  You could always raise an idea for this.

Salesforce1 doesn't have full feature compatibility with the standard UI - in addition to the sharing button, for example, you can't convert leads from the application.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce1 don't have any feature which is related to security settings. These all features are for Administration purpose and Salesforce1 is for Customers (mostly).

Salesforce1 also don't have direct access to setup objects. Administrative and security settings are not available from Salesforce1

For these things SalesforceA looks more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I just logged an idea to allow mobile users to Share records (this is a user function not an admin function). Please vote for this idea:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6OjAAI if your users need to use the "Share" button that appears on records in the normal Salesforce interface.